# How to check if a Flex application is run on a developer machine?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, flexbuilder

I know I could use "BrowserManager.getInstance()" to find out which from URL is my app running, but it doesn't work as I would expect (you can't read url in one line - you have to wait for an event).

Is it possible to do it in some simple way? Like you do in Flash:

```
if (this.getDepth() == -16384)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it

```
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
switch ( lc.domain ){
  case "":
  case "localhost":
    trace('on a dev machine')
    break;
  case 'your.domain.com':
  default:
    trace('not dev so fall through')
}
```

A one liner could be done like

```
if(new LocalConnection().domain == "localhost" )
```

Comment: Great! thanks. Just in case anybody wonders you need "import flash.net.LocalConnection;" too (if it's not added automatically).

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.system.Security;

Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE
```

That tells you when it's running on the web.

Comment: Doesn't work `(Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)` returns true when I run debug in Flash Builder.

Comment: darn, well that works in my company's project (we use that to check if we should expect login data from the webpage). We don't use Flash Builder though, so I dunno.